# Construct a multiindexed dataframe from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose `x = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0,3), 'b': range(1, 4)})` and `y = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(-1,2), 'b': range(2, 5)})`. I want to construct a dataframe `t = pd.DataFrame('x': x, 'y': y)`. The expected result is a multiindexed dataframe. However, an error message tells me `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`.

```
import panda as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0,3), 'b': range(1, 4)})
y = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(-1,2), 'b': range(2, 5)}) 
t = pd.DataFrame('x': x, 'y': y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) by indexes (dafault `axis=0` is omited) for `MultiIndex` in indices:

```
t = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

Or:

```
t = pd.concat([x, y], keys=('x','y'))
```

---

```
print (t)

     a  b
x 0  0  1
  1  1  2
  2  2  3
y 0 -1  2
  1  0  3
  2  1  4
```

Or by columns by `axis=1` for `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
t = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y}, axis=1)
t = pd.concat([x, y], keys=('x','y'), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (t)
   x     y   
   a  b  a  b
0  0  1 -1  2
1  1  2  0  3
2  2  3  1  4
```